# iteration number and thin value in coda.samples

Tags: bayesian, mcmc, jags, rjags

Regarding the following coda.samples in rjags,

```
samples<-coda.samples(jags,
                      c('B', 'A'),
                      5000,thin=5)
```

The iteration is setup as `5000` and the `thin` parameter is setup as `5`. Are there any mechanisms or rules for setting up these two parameters in Bayesian analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "is there a way to define 'correct' or 'optimum' values for these parameters?
If so, then the answer is "No".  Not in R or any language.  You need to look at diagnostics for your model fit (such as trace plots, Gelman-Rubin, Raftery-Lewis and Heidelberger-Welch statistics) and adjusting the parameters of your MCMC process until you get "acceptable" results.  It's an art, not a deterministic algorithm.

You should also look at the number of chains you use, as well as the burn-in, thinning and other parameters of each chain.